# texture paint, assigning material trouble

Tags: materials, texture-painting

when i'm trying to assign material, this happens:[image]

Comment: Can you confirm your normals are pointing outward? The shading of the object looks like it is mixed between inward and outward pointing faces. The black part looks like there is additional geometry in play.

Comment: so what should i do, i dont understand i'm new to blender, pls halp

Comment: Select all the faces and press Ctrl-N to correct normals, see if that helps. Make sure you don't have extra geometry there from accidentally having a selection and pressing F to make a face between.